# A retired professor welcomed me to talk with him after I asked about doing a master thesis

Tags: thesis, masters, communication

(This post is related to [A professor invited me to their seminar when I enquired about working on a master thesis with them: did they reject me?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153882/a-professor-invited-me-to-their-seminar-when-i-enquired-about-working-on-a-maste), I have a follow up question so I decided to open a new post.)

I am an international student in Germany. I sent an email to a professor asking if he could provide me a project for my master thesis. In his reply, he stated that he could not take long term responsibilities since he is retired, but mentioned that I was welcome to meet him for a conversation.

What does that mean? If this is a reject, then what is the conversation for? If he is showing interest in me, then why did he mention that he could not take long term responsibilities?

Comment: Perhaps he is offering to help you consider topics... Some like to help.

Comment: He can’t be interested in talking about the project?

Comment: He might also have ideas for an appropriate supervisor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @Buffy's comment. As a retired professor, he might have little incentive or capacity to take on a new student, which means making sure there are enough funding, guidance, as well as lab space and equipment, etc. However, he might refer you to a suitable professor and help you as a co-advisor in the long term. This is what usually retired professors do when they are still active and collaborate with the university after their retirement.